# Nested columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, columns, beamerposter

I would like to make an A0 poster using the `beamerposter` package. The poster content should appear in `block` environments, for which I need a flexible and clean layout handling. In particular, I need columns and subcolumns.

The best answer to the thread
[Spanning multiple beamer columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/spanning-multiple-beamer-columns)
suggests to simply do **nesting** of `column` environments.

But this doesn't work out nicely. Because the column boundaries do not seem to be neatly aligned, nor is the space between columns the same everywhere. Oddly, the subcolumns are not even centered properly within their "master" column.

Some `hfill` commands and `center` environments do not really help. I tried to embed the blocks into minipages instead of columns, but the problem is similar: unequal and unaligned block boundaries. My understanding of the `multicol` environment is that it won't help either, because what I have are different column layouts stacked on top of each other, which are flanked by yet other columns.

What is a clean solution to this problem?

The result of my current attempt is the following:

[image]

Thanks for help,

---

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug,grid]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

\begin{columns}[t]
  \begin{column}{.24\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{\large First column}
      abc
    \end{block}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{\large Second (double-span) column}
      abc
    \end{block}
    \begin{columns}[t]
      \begin{column}{.24\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{\large First subcolumn}
          abc
        \end{block}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.74\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
            abc
        \end{block}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.24\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{\large Third column}
      abc
    \end{block}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: May be you could consider to change to some other format like [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact `baposter` seems to handle these things better. But I am reluctant to give up `beamerposter` (for different reasons). It's a pity that there are these alignment issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug,grid]{beamerposter}

\newsavebox{\squaredblocktext}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
    \par\vskip\medskipamount%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
            \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\squaredblocktext}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
                \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
            }

            \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
            \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        {\parskip0pt\par}%
        \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}{}
        {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
        \usebeamerfont{block body}%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
                \usebox{\squaredblocktext}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }\vskip\smallskipamount%
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}

        \begin{columns}[t]
            \begin{column}{.24\linewidth}
                \begin{block}{\large First column}
                    abc
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
                \begin{block}{\large Second (double-span) column}
                    abc
                \end{block}
                \begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]
                    \begin{column}{.225\linewidth}
                        \begin{block}{\large First subcolumn}
                            abc
                        \end{block}
                    \end{column}
                    \begin{column}{.725\linewidth}
                        \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
                            abc
                        \end{block}
                    \end{column}
                \end{columns}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.24\linewidth}
                \begin{block}{\large Third column}
                    abc
                \end{block}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]