# Nested Columns in beamer II

Tags: beamer, columns, beamerposter

I am trying to follow [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120186/nested-columns-in-beamer) to properly align columns. I would like to make a poster environtment with one column on the left, and then have the right side broken into a top, which has two columns, and a bottom, which has three. However, doing this the obvious way seems to lead to extra vertical space on the right?

[image: weird vertical alignment?]

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.2,debug]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}[t]

\begin{column}{.25\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{\large First column}
        abc
    \end{block}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.75\linewidth}
    \begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large First subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]
        \begin{column}{.333333\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large First subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.333333\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.333333\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]` to the outermost column. I have also adjusted the widths suitably.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.2,debug]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]
\begin{column}{.245\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{\large First column}
        abc
    \end{block}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.745\linewidth}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large First subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.33\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large First subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.33\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.33\linewidth}
            \begin{block}{\large Second subcolumn}
                abc
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]